# How to calculate the accuracy and error rate in confusion matrix?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, classification, correlation, accuracy, confusion-matrix

[image]

(0 - negative outcome, 1 - positive outcome)

Am I correct? Because I found a different answer.
My answer:
Accuracy rate: TP+TN/ALL(58+25/58+44+23+25)=83/150
Error rate: FN+FP(23+44)= 67/150

Someone say it should be:
Accuracy rate: 58/102
Error rate: 23/48

Answer (score 2):

The 58/102 in your example is TN/N which is specificity, and 23/48 is FN/P which is false negative rate, or 1-sensitivity. Refer to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) for more details.

Comment: does error rate (or this concept) exist in confusion matrix?

Comment: error rate is not commonly used as accuracy, though technically it should be 1-accuracy